# How do I run a background thread on struct data?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've written a priority queue library that keeps the higher-priority elements in memory while periodically evicting low-priority elements to [`rocksdb`](https://docs.rs/rocksdb) which stores them on disk. I'm using this in a search algorithm that can eventually prove that certain elements are no longer useful, and currently, the useless elements are removed lazily when they're encountered again. Since I'm running out of disk space doing this, I'd like to run a background thread on the rocksdb elements to clear them out more eagerly.

The types look like this:

```rs
struct RocksDbWrapper<'w, W, T> {
    scorer: ContextScorer<'w, W, [...]>,   // stores a reference to world
    [...]
    phantom: PhantomData<T>,
}

struct RocksBackedQueue<'w, W, T> {
    world: 'w W,
    db: RocksDbWrapper<'w, W, T>,
    ...
}

struct Search<'a, W, T> {
    world: 'a W,
    queue: RocksBackedQueue<'a, W, T>,
}
```

The search algorithm takes elements out of the queue using [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon)'s parallel iterators, but I can't figure out a way to write an infinite background task with `rayon`.

When I try writing a function in `RocksDbWrapper` to spawn a thread that does the appropriate things, it complains that `self` escapes the associated function. I can understand that, we don't want the thread continuing to run once the DB is dropped.

Then how can I spawn a thread in the search function, have it loop until the search is over, and then exit? I am okay with adding `tokio` or other libraries.

I have tried wrapping the `Search` struct's `queue` member in an `Arc`, and copying that, and passing it to the thread via a channel to avoid capturing `self` but it still happens:

```rs
impl<'a, W, T, L, E> Search<'a, W, T>
where [...]
{
    pub fn search(self) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        let (sender, receiver) = sync_channel(1);
        spawn(move || {
            let sleep_time = Duration::from_secs(10);
            let q: Arc<RocksBackedQueue<W, T>> = receiver.recv().unwrap();
            loop {
                if q.db_len() < 1_000_000 {
                    sleep(sleep_time);
                    continue;
                }
                q.db_cleanup(32_768).unwrap();
            }
        });
        sender.send(self.queue.clone()).unwrap();

        [remainder of search algorithm]
    }
}
```

I get "the parameter type `T` may not live long enough" and "`self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body". I can imagine there could be an issue with the lifetime of the `world` reference, but I understand neither of these errors, given that the `Search` object `self` is not in the closure at all nor should `q` have a reference back to `self`.

What's the best way to approach running a bounded-lifetime but fire-and-forget background task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the best way to approach running a bounded-lifetime but fire-and-forget background task?

Given that you say you are using `rayon` already, the answer is [`rayon::Scope::spawn`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/struct.Scope.html#method.spawn).

You will need to create a `Scope`, in which you spawn the background task and then normally run your parallel iteration. The background task will be able to borrow data that *predates* the creation of the scope (i.e. `self`).

You will also need to arrange to notify that the task should stop when you're done with the foreground activity — otherwise the scope will never return.

(If you were not using `rayon`, then [`std::thread::scope`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) offers similar capabilities. However, this (1) does not use a thread *pool*, just allows you to spawn threads that borrow data.)